# Undefined index: collation laravel 5.1 mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I m using laravel 5.1 to make connection to mysql host.Here is the 
 sample.

```
\Config::set('database.connections.mysql', array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => "host name",
        'port' => 3306,
        'database' => 'db name',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password'
    ));
$data = \DB::connection('mysql')
        ->table('tablename')
        ->get();
```

When i run the above code i get the error::

```
    [ErrorException]            
    Undefined index: collation
```

Comment: As the error states, you're missing the `collation` field in your array. There's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database) available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Laravel is looking for the collation value to use for the connection, but that key doesn't exist in the array you are providing.  Does it work if you add a collation key => value like this? (Note - you should make sure to use the correct collation for your database.)

```
\Config::set('database.connections.mysql', array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => "host name",
        'port' => 3306,
        'database' => 'db name',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
    ));
$data = \DB::connection('mysql')
        ->table('tablename')
        ->get();
```